# Matching a column of cells to another column in Excel

Tags: mac

Ok, I need to compare "A" column to "B" column. I have a billing agency that generates  a number i.e. 00125785231... This number could be in column A at A80 and then in column b at B801... I need something to show in column C801 that it has a match in A column.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what software your using and what version. i.e., Numbers/excel version x.x and did you mean A801 as a typo or did you mean A80 specifically?

Comment: compare by? matching to the same value/name or to what? something like "If (value) A = Value B copy A to C ? so what is your compare basis?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and 2010 excel. jason

Comment: basically there will billing numbers that 2 different people in office will input into rows (they will be billing numbers).  1 person will enter a number into column A and they other will enter into column B. We are trying to track the front side of billing  and the back side. We need to know that it has been billed after the report has been done.

Answer (score 1):

Vlookup will be the answer here.

Eg, given a table:

```
   A,B
   1,5
   2,6
   3,7
   4,8
   5,9
```

In C1 put in, and drag it down:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$6,1,FALSE)),"NOT IN A","IN A")
```

Col A has to be sorted.

Output:

```
A,B,C
1,5,In A
2,6,In A
3,7,Not in A
4,8,Not in A
5,9,Not in A
6, 10,Not in A
```

To deconstruct this:

```
   (VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$6,1,FALSE)
```

VLOOKUP takes your input (B1), and finds that value in the search table (A1:A6). The $ stops this changing as you drag down. It pulls back column 1 of the search table, in this case that's Column A. False tells it not to fuzzy match

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$6,1,FALSE)),"NOT IN A","IN A")
```

Wrapping this in an ISNA tells the IF to print out "NOT IN A" for successful ISNA - ie. where you get NA as a value from the vlookup, meaning it can't find a value. Otherwise, it prints IN A, which is where it can find a value.

Might be more than you care to learn about VLOOKUP (HLOOKUP is the horizontal equivilent), but with a larger search table, you can then pick different values that match your input. This approximates a SQL join.

So, given a table of client data:

```
Name, ID, Phone
Alex, 1, 123-456-7890
Bob, 2, 111-111-1111
Alice, 3, 222-222-2222
Teresa, 4, 333-333-3333
```

You can then create another table with a second set of data, and use a column in that to pull in data from this table.

eg.

```
OrderNum, ClientID, Client Name
1, 3, VLOOKUP - Alice
2, 4, VLOOKUP - Teresa
3, 2, VLOOKUP - Bob
```

This generally useful when given a report to be enriched.

Comment: this works 99% perfect. but when the two do not match it shows N/A.... what the n/a is, can you just leave it blank.1 9 #N/A
2 6 #N/A
2 3 3
3 2 2

Comment: #N/A
1 9 #N/A
2 6 #N/A
2 3 3
3 2 2
  #N/A
1001  #N/A
  #N/A
  #N/A
  #N/A
  #N/A
  #N/A
  #N/A
  #N/A
 1001 1001
  #N/A
  #N/A

Comment: You could wrap that in an IF function and replace N/A with ʹ.

Comment: I updated it earlier with an IF and ISNA - can you try again?

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY. TY, TY, TY.